# Автоматическая смена цветовой темы

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, тёмная-тема

В настройках профиля в графе "Тема" у меня выбрана "Системная настройка". Как я понимаю, это предполагает автоматическую смену темы сайта, исходя из настроек системы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, на данный момент у меня выставлена тема Numix-Dark и данная опция не отрабатывает. Тема сайта как была светлой, так и осталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, Telegram Desktop с такой же включенной опцией работает правильно. Знаю, что это всё-таки приложение, но на всякий случай упомянул.

UPD. Debian 10, Gnome 3.30, Chromium

UPD. 2 В Firefox на удивление всё заработало - всё отрабатывает, сниппет тоже. Видимо, пока хромиум не умеет обрабатывать системную тему. Всем спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему [так-задумано]? Может это как раз косяк реализации, телега ж ловит у ТС изменения темы. На iPadOS у меня адекватно отрабатывает, и твой сниппет тоже. Но здесь только 2 варианта: светлая и темная в системе. В общем, хорошо бы иметь ответ на уровне MSE или MSO для начала.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, если это и баг, то репортать его надо не на MSE, а браузеру. Я ниже привёл код, которым сайт может узнать от браузера тему. Если браузер говорит, что тема светлая, то сайт показывается в светлой теме - так и задумано. Если в системе тема тёмная, а браузер говорит, что светлая, то это ошибка браузера. А ещё есть вариант, что система тоже считает тему светлой, а в телеграме костыль, который проверяет название темы на наличие слова dark. В любом случае, это не баг SO.

Comment: @Qwertiy так это единственный способ вообще? Способ, который использует SO в том числе?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну доступ из скрипта будет задействовать те же механизмы. Опять же, даже если окажется, что браузер разными способами сообщает разный результат (а пока это не доказано), то как узнать, какому из вариантов верить? Сайты всегда работают в песочнице и доступ от них к системе ограничен, так что никто его не пустит выяснять, что там в системных настройках выставлено.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, кстати, а у браузера нет каких-нибудь флагов типа скрытия темы для повышения безопасности, или расширений с такими целями? Вообще, надо бы браузер указать в вопросе, а ещё проверить, будет ли работать так же в приватном окне.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, по идее ещё можно вместо дизайнерских цветов использовать системные, но вряд ли дизайнеры SO на это согласятся. И вообще, я не уверен, как они работают, ни разу ими не пользовался.

Comment: @Qwertiy, браузер хромиум (обновил тело вопроса). Как вы и сказали, попробовал другой браузер (фаерфокс), и на удивление всё заработало - всё отрабатывает, сниппет тоже. Настройки приватности я проверял первым делом, пробовал и так и сяк, там всё глухо. Видимо, пока хромиум не умеет обрабатывать системную тему. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего система или браузер об этом не в курсе. К тому же, тем всего две - тёмная и светлая, и я понятия не имею, определяется ли твоя тема как одна из них. Проверь результат в следующем сниппете:

```css
li { text-decoration: line-through; }
#unsupported { text-decoration: none; }

@media (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference) {
  #no-preference { text-decoration: none; color: blue; }
  #unsupported { text-decoration: line-through; }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  #light { text-decoration: none; color: blue; }
  #unsupported { text-decoration: line-through; }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  #dark { text-decoration: none; color: blue; }
  #unsupported { text-decoration: line-through; }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="no-preference">Пользователь не сделал никаких предпочтений
  <li id="light">Пользователь выбрал светлую тему в операционной системе
  <li id="dark">Пользователь выбрал тёмную тему в операционной системе
  <li id="unsupported">Этот браузер не поддерживает темы
<ul>
```

Comment: пишет выбрана светлая... хотя по факту то стоит тёмная. Спасибо за то, что отреагировали, буду копать с чем связано

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, возможно, тема сама не в курсе, что она тёмная, если её делали до того, как разделение на тёмные и светлые стало популярно - это ж довольно новая штука, а темы существуют давным давно. А сама система как-то сообщает, тёмная тема или всетлая?

Comment: да, тема старая. Ну, смотря что вы имеете в виду под сообщает. Если глянуть в настройки, то никак, разве что только своим названием и цветами. Но как я выше отписывал, на машине установлен Телеграмм клиент, и в нём активна опция *Смена темы на ночную - использовать как в системе* и всё работает как нужно, т.е. при обычной теме  - светлая тема клиента, при моей "тёмной" - тёмная тема клиента. То есть либо система всё таки понимает, либо ТГ обращается напрямую к переменным и вычленяет названия темы, исходя из которого уже решает, какая эта тема

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, а попробуй другой браузер. Я вполне допускаю, что телеграм смотрит в название темы, а не на какой-то специальный признак.